# iPhone 4 app crash for the second launch

Tags: iphone, ios4

I deployed my app in iOS 4.3.2 and installed successfully.

My App runs well through xcode and if i stop the gdb and launch app from device, app crashes at startup

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Recover the crash log in the organizer and check the `callstack`.

Comment: i get a warning as "myapp" exited abnormally with signal 9

Comment: You need the crashlog plist file. Not just the console log.